# Would this be a valid way of proving a trigonometric value despite one of the sides of the triangle being negative?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to prove that this is correct but is using triangles with negative lengths a valid way to do so?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ASGY.jpg

Comment: Tan = opp/adj, you have opp/hyp which is sin.

Comment: OOps, yeah sorry that was a irl typo, if you look at the fraction i still did opp/adj, i just miswrote it :)

Comment: Radius vector or hypotenuse is to be always kept positive. It is better to keep negative $\cos$ value as $\frac{-1}{3}$ and not $\frac{1}{-3}$ so that it establishes the angle in $3,4$ quadrants. And so tan has $\pm $ sign for Q2,Q3 respy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not valid, length can never be negative. You can however use other was to prove your question.

since $\cos\theta $ is negative it lies in either the $2^{nd}$ or $3^{rd}$ quadrant , but the value of $\tan(\theta)$ is positive so the angle $\theta$ must be in the $3^{rd}$ quadrant.

Doing the same thing as you did before but with hypotenuse $3$ gives the result.

Note: You could also use the fact that;

$\tan(\theta) = \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)}}{-\cos(\theta)} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\frac19}}{\frac13}= \sqrt8 =2\sqrt2 $

Comment: yeah I just realised that now anyway thank you and did the same thing, thank you for the help! https://i.imgur.com/mrfkCil.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To use algebraic lengths (i.e. that can take a negative sign), you need to be explicit about the orientation conventions, and specify the positive directions of the lines as well as of the rotation angles.

Usually this is done in the trigonometric circle with a standard coordinate frame, and the oblique lines (hypothenuses/radii) are considered positive, not algebraic.